# How to get modified file from base file and diff file?

Tags: merge, diff, radix

Consider the following example :

```
$ls
base.txt base-modified.txt
$diff base.txt base-modified.txt > diff.txt
$rm base-modified.txt
$
```

I want the base-modified.txt from base.txt and diff.txt...
Can anyone suggest a way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [patch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch).

```
cp base.txt base-modified.txt
patch base-modified.txt diff.txt
```